# Can I assign multiple HREFLANG Attributes to the same Domain?

Tags: seo, local-seo, internationalization, hreflang, rel-alternate

I am working on a website, which is looking to targeting multiple Regions and Languages, using the following Domains:

- www.example.com (American English targeting US Traffic);
- en-gb.example.com (British English, targeting UK Traffic);
- en-au.example.com (Australian English, targeting Australian Traffic)

To help indicate these Regional and Language variations, I have assigned the following `hreflang` Attributes, within the `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://www.example.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="https://en-gb.example.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://en-au.example.com" />
```

**x-default**

As well as targeting American English speakers, in the US, I would also like the `https://www.example.com` Domain to be the 'catch-all' website that targets all traffic that does not fit the other Domains' criteria.  With this in mind, would it be okay to add the `hreflang="x-default"` Attribute so that the `https://www.example.com` Domain ends up with an additional `hreflang` Attribute pointing to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Double-Annotating HREFLANG always alright? What if I remove one of them?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83120/is-double-annotating-hreflang-always-alright-what-if-i-remove-one-of-them)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's perfectly fine to re-use the `https://www.example.com` host as both the en-us and the x-default `hreflang`.

To be sure, you can use the International Targeting Report to debug possible issues after Google crawls your site: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n

It's not mentioned explicitly in the `hreflang` documentation, but you can use the same URL for multiple languages, including the default.

Check out this answer by John Muller about using the same URL for multiple languages:
https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/837326127089729536?